# C++: How to do a linked list with struct passed as parameter?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

So I understand (mostly) the concept of linked lists with pointers. However, I am not sure how I would be able to create a linked list of a struct object, that is passed in a method. Do I need another pointer to point to the pointers on the struct?
My struct contains the pointer:

```
// define a structure to hold bid information
struct Bid {
    string bidId; // unique identifier
    string title;
    string fund;
    double amount;
    Bid *next;
    Bid() {
        amount = 0.0;
        next = NULL;
    }
};
```

And I am passing the struct object to this method to append new Bid structs:

```
  void LinkedList::Append(Bid bid) {
    // FIXME (3): Implement append logic

    //reference bid being passed??? Bid struct has pointers, do we need another pointer?
    Bid *currNode = &bid;

    //set node's next pointer to NULL (end)
    currNode->next = NULL;

    //if list is empty
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = currNode;
        tail = currNode;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = currNode;
        tail = currNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you exact question is

Comment: You don't need to pass the struct. You can just pass a pointer to it.

Comment: I am trying to access the pointer of the struct object being passed, and create a linked list with it. This is how I am used to doing it
`ListAppend(list, newNode) {
   if (list->head == 0) { // List empty
      list->head = newNode
      list->tail = newNode
   }
   else{
      list->tail->next = newNode
      list->tail = newNode
   }
}`

Comment: Is there any reason at all that you are not using `std::forward_list` — yours is a yet another reimplementation, written in a “C with objects” style, with extremely error prone manual memory management. Of thisnis anhomework question — please indicate so.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with passing linked list nodes around by value is that they get copied. You can set a pointer to point to the `bid` value in your function, but that's almost certainly not what you want, because it's going to go away at the end of the function, leaving the pointer dangling. Linked list nodes are virtually always heap-allocated, and passed around by pointer, because you can manually control the lifetime of heap-allocated objects (which is essential here).

Now, what makes this a little problematic from an OO standpoint is that your `Bid` class is violating the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP), in that it's being both a storage for concrete information about a bid *and* a participant in linking certain Bids together. This is one of the reasons you rarely see intrusive containers in OO languages. Depending on your exact use case, it could be preferable to store a pointer-less `Bid` in a `BidNode` which would do the linking. If you did that, you could pass around the `Bid` by value, and copy it into a heap-allocated `BidNode`. Or, of course, you could just use `std::list`.

Comment: There’s no problem with intrusive containers in OO languages, as long as the intrusion is handled as a separate concern. Yes, Bid should have no links in it, but it doesn’t preclude a list implementation from emplacing the object along with the link, implementing an intrusive list without the Bid class knowing anything about it.

Comment: Yes, that was the `BidNode` approach I discussed. But that's still an extrusive container, inasmuch as the object doing the linking is not the same as the ones bring stored.